# How to load JSON file into Laravel (controller and route)

Tags: json, laravel, routes, controller

I'm new to Laravel and trying to load a JSON file into my project (which will then be used for a search function).
NEW EDIT *** It is giving me an error of "undefined constant "data""

For my Controller.php I have:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
  public function index() {
    $results = file_get_contents("http://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/genenames/hgnc/json/locus_groups/protein-coding_gene.json");
    $data = json_decode($results, true);
    dd($data);
    }
  }
```

And for my **new edited route per response below**  web.php I have: (still has the laravel given code in here as well).

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Route::get(“data”, [SiteController::class, “index”]);
```

Comment: go to ``/data`` path ?

Answer (score 1):

In your `web.php` you need import your controller file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
// in laravel 8 and 9 your need to do this with all your controllers
use App\Http\Controllers\SiteController;


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Route::get(“data”, [SiteController::class, “index”]);
```

Comment: Okay great, that took the error out!! Now it's just displaying my home landing page, shouldn't the DD result in it showing me the table?

Comment: @NicoleJaffke maybe, but you can show in your web browser tab networks your petition and show if there it´s dd(). If you don´t show it, maybe you can do a var_dump() with exit() in your function and verify that you´re in this function